# Is it possible to filter key by value type?

Tags: typescript

I want to filter type by Object Type's value type.

is it possible in current typescript specification?

```
type a = {
  a: '123'
}

type b = {
  b: '123'
}

tpye c = {
  a: '123',
}

type map = {
  first: a,
  second: b,
  third: c,
}

type HavingAValueMap = Magic<map>; // pick value with having 'a' property
// { first: {...}, third: {...} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved by Using TS 4.1 new Feature [Key Remapping](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#key-remapping-mapped-types)

```
type a = { a: string}
type b = { b: string}

type map = {
  first: a;
  second: b;
  third: a;
}

type FilterMapType<T, F> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends F ? T[K] : never }

type CheckValidKey<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends never ? never : K;

type FilterObjectByType<T, F> = {[K in keyof T as CheckValidKey<FilterMapType<T, F>, K>]: T[K]}
 
type HavingAValueMap = FilterObjectByType<map, a> // { first: { a: string }, third: { a: string} }
```

Comment: clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are talking about `Omit` util type:

```js
type a = {
    a: '123'
}

type b = {
    b: '123'
}

type c = {
    a: '123',
}

type map = {
    first: a,
    second: b,
    third: c,
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type OmitBy<M, T> = {
    [P in keyof M]: M[P] extends T ? never : M[P]
}[keyof M]

type HavingAValueMap = OmitBy<map, a> 
// {
//    b: '123';
// }
```

Please keep in mind, TS treats types `a` and `c` as equal types because of structural nature of type system

[Here you can find more about structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) You can find more about utils type

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but I want omit type by having property "a".

Answer (score 0):

You could have implemented your magic in a simpler way as follows:

```js
type PickByType<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: T[K];
};
```

The full code, following your example, is in [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeAoKsBcUDkBGATAMzYoC%20KKokUARgsmrVnkSeZeNAMb2rozMCxADRkKVaAFsYYXowBmASwBOAZ2BYYo9KohcA9gDsAJlhraowABYrTULqPYSoABUVcA1gCEQAFU4APL7CUABqAHxy6ADaANJQioZQHhAg%20vJQvrCqmXEAulAQAB7AECY5oVAA-FDxWIYQAG4QynlYvvkA3GTdHNQAEjCNiQDmAIKhMAA2AK4QALIy9G6ePv6QAdJgITDhnUA).